# Which web maps work best for which web services

Tags: web-mapping, google-maps-api, web-service

I'm trying to do a project, where I grab data from a MySQL database, and display it onto a web map API mashup (showing a chart on the map). I want to develop an example using REST, SOAP and possibly OSPF (still undecided) web services. Can anyone help me with info on which map APIs would work best for these web services?

Would Google API maps work for this?

Comment: is your mysql database a spatial database?

Comment: no, all i want is to show real time updates of a static device's health which happens to be llocated in different areas on a map. The only need of the map is when hover over an area where the device is located, it will show me the devices performance metrics

Comment: Leaflet is probably your best bet, but you will have to convert your data into GeoJSON format beforehand so you can consume it as a web feature service WFS). If you are not completely tied to MySQL I would highly suggest you use PostgreSQL instead, because you can then install the PostGIS extension on it and connect to it via Geoserver. This is a pretty standard stack for a web map application and despite there potentially being a lot of pieces, each one isn't that hard to figure out and are all quite useful on their own.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, a really friendly api is [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com). Its really easy to learn, has lots of [plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html), including showing chart on maps plugins (check out DataViz plugins)

So, if i were you i would check Leaflet first.

Answer (score -2):

the best api is ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.x
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/

then leaflet
then openlayer

Comment: Why is it the best?

Comment: because is  Big, heavy Javascript mapping library so you need a little coding experience. You can do more processing with it without adding plugins and it interacts well with ArcGIS products